# No wireless on Kali installation (Realtek)

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, realtek

I have just installed Kali Linux (64) on my laptop, but I haven't been able to get the Wi-Fi to work and unfortunately I don't have an Ethernet port on my laptop. It's worth mentioning that the Wi-Fi was working fine during the Kali installation.

These are what I'm getting when I run the following commands:

iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  Mode:Monitor  Tx-Power=12 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
```

ifconfig:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 16  bytes 960 (960.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 16  bytes 960 (960.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

airmon-ng

```
PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset
phy0    wlan0       ??????      Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8723AU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QS77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller (rev 04)
```

Comment: Run `modprobe 8723au`

Comment: @GAD3R it says `module 8723au not found in directory /lib/modules/4.6.0-kalil-amd64`

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the `linux-headers` and the `build-essential` then build the driver from [lwfinger git repo](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au.git):

```
apt install build-essential git
apt update && apt upgrade && apt dist-upgrade
```

Reboot your system then run:

```
apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au.git
cd rtl8723au
make
make install
modprobe -v 8723au
```

You should recive:

```
insmod /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8723au.ko
```

The wireless module should be correctly loaded.

To make the module available evrey kernel update install `dkms`.

> [To get DKMS to work:](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au/blob/master/README.dkms)
>
> - Install dkms
> - Copy this source to the directory /usr/src/8723au-0.1/
> - Run (as root):
>
> `# dkms add -m 8723au -v 0.1`
>
> - Test a build:
>
> `# dkms build -m 8723au -v 0.1`
>
> From now on this drive should be available for any new kernels.

Comment: Why would the install ISO have it but the distro lack it after the install?

Comment: @jww Because of the kernel update.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `modprobe r8723au`; this realtek card need firmware too. In Debian the package is named `firmware-realtek`